Does resetlocalschema resolve schema mismatch on mixed-versions during an upgrade?
Recently I tried to upgrade my Cassandra cluster (3 + 3) from Cassandra 3.0.15 to 4.1.0 in rolling upgrade manner.
I figured out that when a node with older version act as coordinator, it can't read data from newer version and vice versa so there is a huge inconsistency happening in the middle of the upgrade. I assume its happening because of schema mismatch between C* 3.x and C* 4.x.
Can I use nodetool resetlocalschema in the middle of the upgrade to resolve the schema mismatch between 3.x and 4.x? Please recommend a solution that nullifies the downtime.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Cassandra clusters during major upgrades should have 2 different schema versions, one for each Cassandra version.
As far as I know, this doesn't imply that the coordinators can't read from nodes in different schema versions, unless the keyspaces/tables being read are native schema components that changed in between versions. How did you figure that there was a partition between nodes different versions?
Unless you have a real issue with schema mismatches - in which case you should see 3 or more schema versions in nodetool describecluster - the schema mismatch should be resolved once all the nodes are upgraded, and nodetool resetlocalschema shouldn't do anything until then, and I would still advise against running it.
In the meantime, until the upgrade is completed, please don't make any DDL changes (ALTER, CREATE, DROP), or it could create actual issues with schema mismatches.

Thanks for your answer tavares |
Clusters current status ->  ( 1 x 4.1.4 ) + ( 2 x 3.0.15) |
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded)
|
Above exception occurred when i configured that one Cassandra 4.1.4 node as the coordinator node.

Also I'm constantly getting this [[ ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1} ]] Exception when i try to query using CQL from the 3.0.15 nodes.

The quick answer is no, it won't. It is expected for major versions to have their respective schema versions which will get resolved once all nodes have been upgraded.
The long answer is that your assertion(s) is incorrect, particularly this statement:

... when a node with older version act as coordinator, it can't read data from newer version ...

Nodes are responsible for reading the data they own on disk, not the coordinator, so the binary version isn't relevant. The coordinator simply requests the data from the replicas, and it is the replicas' responsibility to read their own data.
For example, if a read is requested with a consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM on a keyspace that has a local replication factor of 3, the coordinator with request the data from one replica and a digest (hash) from another replica. In both instances, the replicas will provide their respective responses to coordinator so the reads are independent of the Cassandra version installed.
If you're running into schema disagreements during reads, the most likely cause is that one (or more) schema change was made in the middle of the upgrade. While running in mixed-versions, schema cannot be propagated to nodes with a different version since those schema are not compatible.
For this reason, schema changes is not allowed during major upgrades since the different schemas can never be resolved even after all nodes are upgraded. If the schema is altered in mixed-versions, there are certain scenarios which are unrecoverable and some SSTables may be unreadable. Cheers!

Thanks for your answer erick | Clusters current status -> ( 1 x 4.1.4 ) + ( 2 x 3.0.15) | Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were required but only 1 replica responded) | Above exception occurred when i configured that one Cassandra 4.1.4 node as the coordinator node.

And also I'm getting this [[ ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1} ]] Exception when i try to query using CQL from the 3.0.15 nodes.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/339129/inconsistency-in-the-middle-of-cassandra-rolling-upgrade-from-cassandra-3-0-15-t
